# django fails to import wsgi after restructuring?

Tags: python, django, wsgi, gunicorn, django-wsgi

My initial project structure is like this:

```
manage.py
foo/
  wsgi.py
  settings.py
  urls.py
  __init__.py
```

manage.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "foo.settings")

    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line

    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

New structure:

```
manage.py
src/
   foo/
      wsgi.py
      settings.py
      urls.py
      __init__.py
```

manage.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys
project_root = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

print project_root 

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sys.path.insert(0, os.path.join(project_root, 'src'))

    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "foo.settings")

    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line

    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

Then during the deployment, I have this error of `ImportError: No module named foo.wsgi`:

```
$ gunicorn foo.wsgi:application 
2017-05-20 16:53:31 [19107] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 18.0
2017-05-20 16:53:31 [19107] [INFO] Listening at: http://127.0.0.1:8000 (19107)
2017-05-20 16:53:31 [19107] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2017-05-20 16:53:31 [19111] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 19111
2017-05-20 16:53:31 [19111] [ERROR] Exception in worker process:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/www/html/django-project/foo/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 495, in spawn_worker
    worker.init_process()
  File "/var/www/html/django-project/foo/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 106, in init_process
    self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
  File "/var/www/html/django-project/foo/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 114, in wsgi
    self.callable = self.load()
  File "/var/www/html/django-project/foo/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 62, in load
    return self.load_wsgiapp()
  File "/var/www/html/django-project/foo/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 49, in load_wsgiapp
    return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
  File "/var/www/html/django-project/foo/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 354, in import_app
    __import__(module)
ImportError: No module named foo.wsgi
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/www/html/django-project/foo/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 495, in spawn_worker
    worker.init_process()
  File "/var/www/html/django-project/foo/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 106, in init_process
    self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
  File "/var/www/html/django-project/foo/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 114, in wsgi
    self.callable = self.load()
  File "/var/www/html/django-project/foo/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 62, in load
    return self.load_wsgiapp()
  File "/var/www/html/django-project/foo/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 49, in load_wsgiapp
    return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
  File "/var/www/html/django-project/foo/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 354, in import_app
    __import__(module)
ImportError: No module named foo.wsgi
2017-05-20 16:53:31 [19111] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 19111)
2017-05-20 16:53:31 [19107] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
2017-05-20 16:53:31 [19107] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
```

django fails to import wsgi after restructuring

wsgi.py

```
import os

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "foo.settings")

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Any ideas?

**EDIT:**

I get it running with:

```
$ gunicorn src.foo.wsgi:application 
2017-05-20 17:33:52 [22227] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 18.0
2017-05-20 17:33:52 [22227] [INFO] Listening at: http://127.0.0.1:8000 (22227)
2017-05-20 17:33:52 [22227] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2017-05-20 17:33:52 [22231] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 22231
```

But when I access the site at http://127.0.0.1:8000/, i get this error:

```
2017-05-20 17:33:59 [22231] [ERROR] Error handling request
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/www/html/django-project/foo/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/sync.py", line 131, in handle_request$ gunicorn src.foo.wsgi:application 
2017-05-20 17:33:52 [22227] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 18.0
2017-05-20 17:33:52 [22227] [INFO] Listening at: http://127.0.0.1:8000 (22227)
2017-05-20 17:33:52 [22227] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2017-05-20 17:33:52 [22231] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 22231
2017-05-20 17:33:59 [22231] [ERROR] Error handling request
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/www/html/django-project/foo/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/sync.py", line 131, in handle_request
    respiter = self.wsgi(environ, resp.start_response)
  File "/var/www/html/django-project/foo/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 236, in __call__
    self.load_middleware()
  File "/var/www/html/django-project/foo/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 43, in load_middleware
    for middleware_path in settings.MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES:
  File "/var/www/html/django-project/foo/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 53, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/var/www/html/django-project/foo/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 48, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/var/www/html/django-project/foo/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 134, in __init__
    raise ImportError("Could not import settings '%s' (Is it on sys.path?): %s" % (self.SETTINGS_MODULE, e))
ImportError: Could not import settings 'foo.settings' (Is it on sys.path?): No module named foo.settings
2017-05-20 17:33:59 [22231] [ERROR] Error handling request
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/www/html/django-project/foo/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/sync.py", line 131, in handle_request
    respiter = self.wsgi(environ, resp.start_response)
  File "/var/www/html/django-project/foo/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 236, in __call__
    self.load_middleware()
  File "/var/www/html/django-project/foo/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 43, in load_middleware
    for middleware_path in settings.MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES:
  File "/var/www/html/django-project/foo/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 53, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/var/www/html/django-project/foo/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 48, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/var/www/html/django-project/foo/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 134, in __init__
    raise ImportError("Could not import settings '%s' (Is it on sys.path?): %s" % (self.SETTINGS_MODULE, e))
ImportError: Could not import settings 'foo.settings' (Is it on sys.path?): No module named foo.settings

    respiter = self.wsgi(environ, resp.start_response)
  File "/var/www/html/django-project/foo/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 236, in __call__
    self.load_middleware()
  File "/var/www/html/django-project/foo/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 43, in load_middleware
    for middleware_path in settings.MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES:
  File "/var/www/html/django-project/foo/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 53, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/var/www/html/django-project/foo/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 48, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/var/www/html/django-project/foo/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 134, in __init__
    raise ImportError("Could not import settings '%s' (Is it on sys.path?): %s" % (self.SETTINGS_MODULE, e))
ImportError: Could not import settings 'foo.settings' (Is it on sys.path?): No module named foo.settings
2017-05-20 17:33:59 [22231] [ERROR] Error handling request
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/www/html/django-project/foo/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/sync.py", line 131, in handle_request
    respiter = self.wsgi(environ, resp.start_response)
  File "/var/www/html/django-project/foo/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 236, in __call__
    self.load_middleware()
  File "/var/www/html/django-project/foo/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 43, in load_middleware
    for middleware_path in settings.MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES:
  File "/var/www/html/django-project/foo/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 53, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/var/www/html/django-project/foo/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 48, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/var/www/html/django-project/foo/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 134, in __init__
    raise ImportError("Could not import settings '%s' (Is it on sys.path?): %s" % (self.SETTINGS_MODULE, e))
ImportError: Could not import settings 'foo.settings' (Is it on sys.path?): No module named foo.settings
```

**EDIT 2:**

I have to add a `src.` to all `foo.`:

```
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "src.foo.settings")
ROOT_URLCONF = 'src.foo.urls'
```

Any better ways of doing it?

Comment: Is `manage.py` used to start the server in gunicorn (never used it). If you can `manage.py runserver` ok, then I would guess that gunicorn hasn't gotten `src` to its `PYTHONPATH`..

Comment: @thebjorn `Is manage.py used to start the server in gunicorn (never used it)` what do u mean?

Comment: How do you get gunicorn to start your server?  You're fixing your path in `manage.py`, perhaps you need to do something similar when you start the server from gunicorn?

Comment: @thebjorn this is how to start it `(env) xxx@xxx-desktop:/var/www/html/django-project/foo/foo$ gunicorn foo.wsgi:application `

Comment: ok.. now how is gunicorn supposed to find `foo.wsgi` from there?  Can you run `python -c "import foo.wsgi"` from there?  If not, then your `PYTHONPATH` is not set up correctly (check which directories it includes, e.g. by printing `sys.path`) -- you need to set it up correctly.

Comment: @thebjorn i will get an error for `$ python -c "import foo.wsgi"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named foo.wsgi`

Comment: As I said, your `PYTHONPATH` is not set up correctly, you need to set it up correctly (or add `__init__.py` files in `src` and `foo` and change the `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` and gunicorn start command to use `src.foo.wsgi`.

Comment: @thebjorn i got it running by `$ gunicorn src.foo.wsgi:application ` but new errors afterwards. see my edit above. thanks. how do i set `PYTHONPATH`?

Comment: Please read the tracebacks. Anyways, those are new questions (and I have to take the dog out for some fun.. good luck ;-)

Comment: @thebjorn i got it running now. enjoy the walk! :-)

Answer (score 0):

`manage.py` is completely irrelevant here, as you don't use it when you start gunicorn.

The problem is probably that you need an empty `__init__.py` inside the `foo` directory to make it a package that Python can import.

Comment: got it running now but a bit tedious. see my edit 2. thanks.